# old versions of Ubuntu Packages in ISO or rar please

Tags: upgrade, updates, dvd, cd

Hi there Ubuntu and Developers its possible to create ISO  images to burn on CD DVD or USB  pen
all old versions Updates Packages   from  Ubuntu 18.0.04, 19, 20, 21 and so on

my favorite Ubuntu version is Groovy  but the main problem is i need to install  the updates for some apps i have to work  or it won't install and shows failed  needs upgrade

it makes me to reisntall always new versions of Ubuntu and i do not want that i m happy with the Ubuntu  i have as Groovy  i like this one and i do not mine to use old versions  at all

could you guys create this and send me the link for download the image as ISO and  easy to install on Ubuntu Groovy  without  many  compleces i m not much familiar with Command lines

GUI  its easy and fast  and  all new generation Operation Systems should be as GUI

please let me know guys

Answer (score 3):

Old ISO are already available for download/install; and we QA-test (*Quality Assurance test*) those ISOs prior to release to ensure you install without internet connection (*on ISOs where it makes sense; not netboot*), so nothing more should be required.

https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

To add additional packages, apply upgrades etc (*which won't be security fixes post-EOL being reached*) you'll need to adjust the sources as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades as the release is *end of life*.

Comment: i dont mind to use the old versions as i said and i do not like to be  on the front line to many bugs to fix after

Comment: Sorry I don't follow your logic... The most serious bugs are in most cases the security flaws, which are **not** fixed on EOL releases... in fact I recall a somewhat *recent* release that reached EOL on the day major security flaw fix(es) were rolled out.. the EOL release however missed out (*its EOL was announced first; users got the fix(es) after release-upgrade to a supported release*) which occurs somewhat often.  Most of us are on-line thus security matters!